# Is there any way to increase code coverage of apex class?

Tags: salesforce, code-coverage, apex, test-class

I have tried multiples ways to achieve more than 80% code coverage for this apex class but fail to do that. I have tried (Test.isRunningTest()) as well to cover the single query.

`public with sharing class FetchMultipleRecords {
// Method to fetch all the quantification records from Drawing Line Items Object.

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static String selectDPRRecord(String dprID) {
    System.debug('dprID: ' + dprID);
    List<DPR__c> dpr = [SELECT Id, Execution__c FROM DPR__c WHERE Id = :dprID  LIMIT 1];
    return dpr[0].Execution__c;
    
}
@AuraEnabled
public static void updateDPRPlanforTomorrow(String dprID, String planforTomorrow, Date nextWorkingDate, Decimal nooflabors, Decimal noofhours ) {
    System.debug('dprID: ' + dprID + ' | planforTomorrow: ' + planforTomorrow + '| nextWorkingDate: '+ nextWorkingDate + '| nooflabors:' + nooflabors +'| noofhours : '+noofhours);
    DPR__c dpr = [SELECT Id, Execution__c, Plan_for_Tomorrow__c,Number_of_Labors__c,Number_of_Hours__c FROM DPR__c WHERE Id = :dprID LIMIT 1];
    DPR__c updateDpr = dpr;
    updateDpr.Plan_for_Tomorrow__c = planforTomorrow;
    updateDpr.DPR_Generated_By__c = UserInfo.getUserId();
    updateDpr.DPR_generated_date__c = System.Date.today();
    updateDpr.Next_Working_Date__c = nextWorkingDate;
    updateDpr.Number_of_Labors__c = nooflabors;
    updateDpr.Number_of_Hours__c = noofhours;
    
    update dpr;
    System.debug('dprID: ' + dprID + ' | planforTomorrow: ' + planforTomorrow + '| nextWorkingDate: '+ nextWorkingDate + '| nooflabors:' + nooflabors +'| noofhours : '+noofhours);
}

@AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
public static List<Installation__c> getActivities(String projectName) {
    return [
        SELECT Id, Name, Drawing_ID__r.Formula_Name__c, Floor__c, Installation_Activity__c, Execution__r.Name
        FROM Installation__c 
        WHERE Execution__c = :projectName AND No_of_Line_Items__c>0
    ];
    
}

@AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
public static List<Installation_Line_Items__c> getInstallationActivitiesForFloor(
    String installationActivity,
    String floor,
    String installationId
) {
    return [
        SELECT
        Id,
        Floor__c,
        Installation_Activity__c,
        Project_Items__c,
        Project_Items__r.SAP_Item_Code__c,
        Project_Items__r.Item_Description__c,
        Project_Items__r.Total_BOQ_Quantity__c,
        Project_Items__r.Total_installed_Quantity__c,
        Project_Items__r.BOQ_Description__c,
        Project_Items__r.Total_Shop_Drawing_Quantity__c,
        Installation__r.Execution__r.Name,
        Floor_cutting_JB_floor__c,
        Floor_chipping_JB_floor__c,
        Raceway_Junction_box_marking_JB__c,
        Raceway_cutting_laying_JB_floor__c,
        Raceway_earthing_JB_floor__c,
        Raceway_conduit_laying_JB_floor__c,
        Raceway_clamp_installation_JB_floor__c,
        Raceway_filling_JB_floor__c,
        Junction_box_installation_JB_floor__c,
        Junction_box_packing_JB_floor__c,
        av_conduit_installation_conduit__c,
        AV_Switch_plate_installation_SS__c,
        AV_power_point_circuit_wires_laying__c,
        Access_security_Switch_plate_installat__c,
        Access_security_power_point_circuit__c,
        Armoured_cable_laying_HT__c,
        Armoured_cable_laying__c,
        bms_conduit_installation_Conduit__c,
        Back_box_installation_SS__c,
        Back_box_marking_SS__c,
        Busduct_installation__c,
        Bucholz_relay_installation__c,
        CCTV_conduit_installation_Conduit__c,
        CSS_USS_Installation_on_foundation__c,
        CSS_neutral_earth_strip_w_terminal__c,
        Cable_cutting_Armoured__c,
        Cable_cutting_HT__c,
        Cable_dressing_Armoured__c,
        Cable_dressing_HT__c,
        Cable_laying_dressing_inside_equiments__c,
        Cable_tag_installation_ENDT__c,
        Cable_tag_installation_Earthing_cable__c,
        Cable_tag_installation_HT__c,
        Cable_tray_Ceiling_trunking_bend_fabricn__c,
        Cable_tray_Ceiling_trunking_bend_install__c,
        Cable_terimination_in_busbar__c,
        Cable_terimination_in_busbar_ENDT__c,
        Cable_tray_Ceiling_trunking_clamp_instal__c,
        Cable_tray_Ceiling_trunking_laying__c,
        Cable_tray_Ceiling_trunking_cover_laying__c,
        Cable_tray_Ceiling_trunking_support_inst__c,
        Ceiling_rose_installation__c,
        Circuit_conduit_Trunking_terminate_wit__c,
        Circuit_ferruling_Lighting__c,
        Circuit_ferruling_Raceway__c,
        Circuit_laying_in_DB_frame_and_DB__c,
        Connec_busbar_Panel__c,
        Connect_busbar_HT__c,
        Connect_cable_shield_with_body_earthing__c,
        Connect_earthing_strip_with_earthing_ter__c,
        Connect_earthing_strip_with_termination__c,
        Connect_neutral_earth_strip_w_terminal__c,
        Conservator_Tank_installation__c,
        DB_Chart_DB_tag_hanging__c,
        DB_Trunking_installation__c,
        DB_Wall_marking__c,
        DB_Installation__c,
        DB_dressing_work__c,
        Earth_box_installation_Earthing_cable__c,
        Earthing_cable_laying__c,
        Earthing_cable_termination_Earthing_cab__c,
        Earthing_clamp_installation__c,
        Earthing_strip_connection__c,
        Earthing_strip_laying__c,
        Earthing_strip_route_marking__c,
        Explosion_vent_installation__c,
        Filling_oil_tank_of_transformer__c,
        Foundation_fabrication__c,
        Foundation_footprint_marking_CSS__c,
        Foundation_footprint_marking__c,
        Gland_and_earthing_ring_fixing_in_cable__c,
        Gland_earthing_connection_ENDT__c,
        HT_Cable_laying_inside_cable_chamber__c,
        HT_Cable_shield_connected_w_earth_strip__c,
        HT_Cable_tag_installation__c,
        HT_Cable_terimination_in_busbar__c,
        HT_Lugs_installation_and_crimping__c,
        Highest_Labor_on_a_day__c,
        HT_make_hole_or_cut_in_gland_plate__c,
        Input_and_output_cable_laying_work__c,
        HVAC_power_points_conduit_installation__c,
        jb_cover_installation_conduit__c,
        Installation_of_all_accessories__c,
        LV_Switch_plate_installation_SS__c,
        LV_power_point_circuit_wires_laying__c,
        Light_Fixture_Installation__c,
        Light_fixtures_marking__c,
        Lay_Cable_in_equipment_s_cable_chamber__c,
        Light_fixtures_tagging__c,
        Lighting_conduit_installation_Conduit__c,
        Light_fixtures_wiring_connection__c,
        Lighting_point_circuit_wires_laying__c,
        Line_out_cable_tray_Ceiling_trunking_rou__c,
        Lugs_installation_and_crimping_ENDT__c,
        Line_out_conduit_route_Conduit__c,
        Lugs_installation_and_crimping_HT__c,
        Mark_location_of_equipment_s_on_floor__c,
        Mark_the_footprint_of_UPS_inverter_bat__c,
        Outer_cover_installation__c,
        Panel_installation_HT__c,
        partition_conduit_dropping_conduit__c,
        Panel_installation__c,
        Phase_reversal_box_bustduct_installed__c,
        Power_conduit_installation_Conduit__c,
        RAW_Power_point_circuit_wires_laying__c,
        Radiator_installation__c,
        Raw_power_cable_laying_Raceway__c,
        Raw_power_switch_plate_installation_SS__c,
        Switch_plate_connection_with_circuit_S__c,
        Silica_Breather_installation__c,
        Saddle_spacer_installation_Conduit__c,
        Switch_socket_looping_SS__c,
        Rising_mains_installation__c,
        Switch_plate_tagging_SS__c,
        Switch_socket_assemble_SS__c,
        Tightening_of_all_joints__c,
        Transformer_shifted_at_desire_location__c,
        UPS_Power_point_circuit_wires_laying__c,
        UPS_inverter_batteries_commissioning__c,
        UPS_inverter_batteries_installation__c,
        UPS_power_cable_laying_Raceway__c,
        UPS_power_switch_plate_installation_SS__c,
        VAV_HVAC_Switch_plate_installation_SS__c,
        VAV_HVAC_power_point_circuit_wires_lay__c,
        WIFI_conduit_installation_Conduit__c,
        Workstations_switch_plate_installation__c,
        base_frame_installation_HT__c,
        align_all_pieces_of_bus_duct__c,
        base_frame_installation__c,
        check_continuity_IR_values_after_cut_AR__c,
        check_continuity_IR_values_after_cut_HT__c,
        check_continuity_IR_values_before_cut_AR__c,
        check_continuity_IR_values_before_cut_HT__c,
        connect_control_wiring_Panel__c,
        control_cable_laying_b_w_MB_and_AUX__c,
        connect_control_wiring_HT__c,
        make_the_appropriate_size_of_hole_ENDT__c,
        line_out_route_marking_of_bus_duct__c,
        make_the_appropriate_size_of_hole_HT__c,
        marking_of_Panel_dimension_HT__c,
        marking_of_Panel_dimension__c,
        marking_of_metering_Kiosk_dimension__c,
        metering_Kiosk_Installation__c,
        rodent_conduit_installation_conduit__c,
        suspenders_installation__c,
        tie_bunch_cable_Earthing_cable__c,
        tie_bunch_cable_Raceway__c,
        Total_installed_quantity_DPR_Quantity__c,
        Manhours__c,
        Total_No_Of_Tasks__c
        FROM Installation_Line_Items__c
        WHERE
        Installation_Activity__c = :installationActivity
        AND Floor__c = :floor
        AND Installation__c = :installationId
        AND Installation__r.No_of_Line_Items__c > 0 AND Project_Items__r.Item_Group_Name__c !='Consumable' AND Project_Items__r.Item_Group_Name__c !=null
    ];
}
@AuraEnabled
public static void insertDPRLineItems(String dprli) 
{
   
    List<DPR_Line_Items__c> addDPRLI = new List<DPR_Line_Items__c>();
    List<Installation_Line_Items__c> addILI = new List<Installation_Line_Items__c>();
    // -----------------------------------------CABLE TRAY------------------------------------------------------
    List<DPRLICableTray> c = (List<DPRLICableTray>)JSON.deserialize(dprli,List<DPRLICableTray>.class);
    System.debug('c. '+c.size());
    for(DPRLICableTray edprli : c){
        if (edprli.InstallationActivityc == 'Cable Tray') { 
            Integer count = 0;
            System.debug('c.edprli '+edprli.NumberOfLaboursc);    
            DPR_Line_Items__c dli = new DPR_Line_Items__c();
            dli.DPR__c = edprli.DPR;
            dli.Installation_Line_Items_ID__c=edprli.InstallationLineItemsIDc;
            System.debug('InstallationLineItemsIDc :'+ edprli.InstallationLineItemsIDc);
            dli.Daily_Measure_Quantity__c = edprli.DailyMeasureQuantityc;
            dli.Number_Of_hours__c = edprli.NumberOfhoursc;
            dli.Number_Of_Labours__c = edprli.NumberOfLaboursc;
            dli.Project_Items__c = edprli.ProjectItemsc;
            dli.Installation_Activity__c= edprli.InstallationActivityc;
            dli.Floor__c= edprli.Floorc;
            dli.Line_out_CABT_Ceiling_trunking_route__c = edprli.LineoutCABTCeilingtrunkingroutec;
            dli.CABT_Ceiling_trunking_support_instn__c = edprli.CABTCeilingtrunkingsupportinstnc;
            dli.CABT_Ceiling_trunking_bend_fabrication__c = edprli.CABTCeilingtrunkingbendfabricationc;
            dli.CABT_Ceiling_trunking_laying__c = edprli.CABTCeilingtrunkinglayingc;
            dli.CABT_Ceiling_trunking_bend_installation__c = edprli.CABTCeilingtrunkingbendinstallationc;
            dli.Cable_tray_Ceiling_trunking_cover_laying__c = edprli.CabletrayCeilingtrunkingcoverlayingc;
            dli.CABT_Ceiling_trunking_clamp_instal__c = edprli.CABTCeilingtrunkingclampinstalc;
            addDPRLI.add(dli);
            System.debug('dli: '+ dli);
            
            //-------------UPDATE CABLE TRAY INSTALLATION LINE ITEM WITH CABLE TRAY DPR LINE ITEMS--------------
            Installation_Line_Items__c ili = new Installation_Line_Items__c();
            ili.Id = edprli.InstallationLineItemsIDc;
            ili.Total_installed_quantity_DPR_Quantity__c = edprli.TotalinstalledquantityDPRQuantityc + edprli.DailyMeasureQuantityc;
            ili.Cable_tray_Ceiling_trunking_cover_laying__c = edprli.CabletrayCeilingtrunkingcoverlayingc;
            ili.Line_out_cable_tray_Ceiling_trunking_rou__c = edprli.LineoutCABTCeilingtrunkingroutec;
            ili.Cable_tray_Ceiling_trunking_support_inst__c = edprli.CABTCeilingtrunkingsupportinstnc;
            ili.Cable_tray_Ceiling_trunking_bend_fabricn__c = edprli.CABTCeilingtrunkingbendfabricationc;
            ili.Cable_tray_Ceiling_trunking_laying__c = edprli.CABTCeilingtrunkinglayingc;
            ili.Cable_tray_Ceiling_trunking_bend_install__c = edprli.CABTCeilingtrunkingbendinstallationc;
            ili.Cable_tray_Ceiling_trunking_clamp_instal__c = edprli.CABTCeilingtrunkingclampinstalc;
            ili.Manhours__c= edprli.Manhoursc + (edprli.NumberOfhoursc * edprli.NumberOfLaboursc);
            //if (edprli.HighestLaboronadayc < edprli.NumberOfLaboursc || edprli.HighestLaboronadayc == null || edprli.HighestLaboronadayc == 0) {
            ili.Highest_Labor_on_a_day__c= edprli.NumberOfLaboursc;
            // }
            ili.Total_No_Of_Tasks__c= 7;
            
            if (edprli.CabletrayCeilingtrunkingcoverlayingc == 'Completed') {
                count += 1;
            }
            if (edprli.LineoutCABTCeilingtrunkingroutec == 'Completed') {
                count += 1;
            }
            if (edprli.CABTCeilingtrunkingsupportinstnc == 'Completed') {
                count += 1;
            }
            if (edprli.CABTCeilingtrunkingbendfabricationc == 'Completed') {
                count += 1;
            }
            if (edprli.CABTCeilingtrunkinglayingc == 'Completed') {
                count += 1;
            }
            if (edprli.CABTCeilingtrunkingbendinstallationc == 'Completed') {
                count += 1;
            }
            if (edprli.CABTCeilingtrunkingclampinstalc == 'Completed') {
                count += 1;
            }
            
            ili.Total_No_Of_Tasks_Completed__c=count;
            addILI.add(ili);
        }
    } 
    
    // -----------------------------------------CLASSES END---------------
    if (addDPRLI.size() > 0) {
        insert addDPRLI;
        System.debug('addDPRLI value after insert: '+ addDPRLI);
    }
    if (addILI.size() > 0) {
        update addILI;
        System.debug('addILI value after insert: '+ addILI);
    }
}

// -----------------------------------------CABLE TRAY WRAPPER CLASS---------------------------------------------------
public class DPRLICableTray{
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public String DPR {get; set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public Decimal TotalinstalledquantityDPRQuantityc{get; set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public Decimal Manhoursc {get; set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public String InstallationLineItemsIDc {get; set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public Decimal DailyMeasureQuantityc {get; set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public Decimal NumberOfLaboursc {get; set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public Decimal NumberOfhoursc {get; set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public id ProjectItemsc {get; set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public string InstallationActivityc {get; set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public string Floorc {get; set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public string LineoutCABTCeilingtrunkingroutec {get; set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public string CABTCeilingtrunkingclampinstalc {get; set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public string CABTCeilingtrunkingsupportinstnc {get; set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public string CABTCeilingtrunkingbendfabricationc {get; set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public string CABTCeilingtrunkinglayingc {get; set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public string CABTCeilingtrunkingbendinstallationc {get; set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public string CabletrayCeilingtrunkingcoverlayingc {get; set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public Decimal TotalNoOfTasksc  {get; set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public Decimal HighestLaboronadayc  {get; set;}
    
    
    
    public DPRLICableTray (
        String DPR,
        Decimal DailyMeasureQuantityc,
        Decimal NumberOfLaboursc,
        Decimal NumberOfhoursc,
        Id ProjectItemsc,
        String InstallationLineItemsIDc,
        string InstallationActivityc,
        string Floorc,
        string LineoutCABTCeilingtrunkingroutec,
        string CABTCeilingtrunkingclampinstalc,
        string CABTCeilingtrunkingsupportinstnc,
        string CABTCeilingtrunkingbendfabricationc,        
        string CABTCeilingtrunkinglayingc,
        string CABTCeilingtrunkingbendinstallationc,
        string CabletrayCeilingtrunkingcoverlayingc,
        Decimal TotalinstalledquantityDPRQuantityc,
        Decimal Manhoursc,
        Decimal HighestLaboronadayc
    ){
        this.DPR = DPR;
        this.InstallationLineItemsIDc= InstallationLineItemsIDc;
        this.DailyMeasureQuantityc = DailyMeasureQuantityc;
        this.NumberOfLaboursc = NumberOfLaboursc;
        this.NumberOfhoursc = NumberOfhoursc;
        this.InstallationActivityc= InstallationActivityc;
        this.ProjectItemsc= ProjectItemsc;
        this.Floorc= Floorc;
        this.LineoutCABTCeilingtrunkingroutec = LineoutCABTCeilingtrunkingroutec;
        this.CABTCeilingtrunkingsupportinstnc = CABTCeilingtrunkingsupportinstnc;
        this.CABTCeilingtrunkingbendfabricationc = CABTCeilingtrunkingbendfabricationc;
        this.CABTCeilingtrunkinglayingc = CABTCeilingtrunkinglayingc;
        this.CABTCeilingtrunkingbendinstallationc = CABTCeilingtrunkingbendinstallationc;
        this.CabletrayCeilingtrunkingcoverlayingc = CabletrayCeilingtrunkingcoverlayingc;
        this.CABTCeilingtrunkingclampinstalc = CABTCeilingtrunkingclampinstalc;
        this.TotalinstalledquantityDPRQuantityc = TotalinstalledquantityDPRQuantityc;
        this.Manhoursc = Manhoursc;
        this.HighestLaboronadayc = HighestLaboronadayc;
        this.TotalNoOfTasksc= 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: what's your test class, which lines aren't covered...